# Unexpected data when opening a file received from a controller action as a stream response in NestJS

Tags: angular, nestjs

Issue: I have an action in my controller that should send a file as a response to a request (I'm sending a stream). On the client side (Angular), I receive the response and save the file to the computer. However, when I open the file, instead of "This text must be in file", it contains the following data:

[image]

Code in server:

```
@Controller('/logger')
export class ActivityLogController {

  @Get('/file')
  @ApiQuery({
    name: 'username',
    description: 'Username',
    required: false,
    examples: {
      admin: { value: 'admin' },
      guest: { value: 'guest' }
    } 
  })
  @ApiOkResponse({description: 'File'})
  async getFile(
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
    @Query('username') username?: string,
  ){

    const fileName = `${username ?? 'guest'} ${new Date().toISOString().replace('.', '_')}.log`;

    const textInFile = "This text must be in file";

    const readableStream = Readable.from(textInFile);
   
    res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName};"`,
      'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'content-disposition'
    });

    return new StreamableFile(readableStream);

  }

}
```

Method of saving file in cient side (Angular)

```
async downloadActivityLogs(userName: string) {

    let params = new HttpParams().set('username', userName);

    await this.downloadLogs(
      this.activityUrl, //url 
      params,
      (response: IBlobDto) => { //callback on success response
      
        saveAs(response.fileContent, response.filename);//import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
        const msg = `Activity logs downloaded successfully: ${response.filename}`;
        this.logger.infoSuccess({
          message: msg,
          method: this.downloadActivityLogs.name,
          source: 'LoggerStorageService'
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

interface IBlobDto:

```
export interface IBlobDto {
  filename: string;
  fileContent: Blob
}
```

Instead of this content in file:

[image]

I expect the file to contain a string "This text must be in file".

What do I do wrong?